# A subquery returning multple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-agile-plm

I am getting an error in the below query.. can anyone help fixing this query

```
select c.CHANGE_NUMBER, 
(select le.ENTRYVALUE from listentry  le
where le.ENTRYID = c.CATEGORY)as CATEGORY ,
(
            SELECT  last_name || ',' || first_name || '(' || loginid || ')'
            FROM agileuser
            WHERE id = c.ORIGINATOR
        ) initiator,(
            SELECT  last_name || ',' || first_name || '(' || loginid || ')'
            FROM agileuser
            WHERE id = c.owner
        ) coordinator, w.state,

(SELECT description
            FROM nodetable
            WHERE id = w.state
        ) workflow_status , TO_CHAR(w.LOCAL_DATE,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')local_date,
      (select  
        (trunc(to_date(B.local_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(w.local_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')))as timediff
        FROM WORKFLOW_PROCESS w INNER JOIN WORKFLOW_PROCESS B ON B.order_by = (w.order_by + 1) 
        where w.change_id=B.Change_id and w.change_id=9946301 )--ORDER BY w.order_by ASC 

       from change c, WORKFLOW_PROCESS w 
        where w.change_id = c.id-- order by w.ORDER_BY)
       and c.CHANGE_NUMBER='NPI001084' 
      order by w.ORDER_BY,local_date ASC
```

The trunc() query gives multiple records

```
 select  
     (trunc(to_date(B.local_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(w.local_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')))as timediff
      FROM WORKFLOW_PROCESS w INNER JOIN WORKFLOW_PROCESS B ON B.order_by = (w.order_by + 1) 
      where w.change_id=B.Change_id and w.change_id=9946301 ORDER BY w.order_by ASC
```

hence not able to run along with this main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely untested, and probably with some typos, also possibly joins that should be left joins, and maybe incorrect oracle syntax, but...

```
select c.CHANGE_NUMBER, 
    le.ENTRYVALUE as CATEGORY
    orig.last_name || ',' || orig.first_name || '(' || orig.loginid || ')' as initiator,
    own.last_name || ',' || own.first_name || '(' || own.loginid || ')' as coordinator,
    w.state,
    n.description as workflow_status,
    TO_CHAR(w.LOCAL_DATE,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')local_date,
    trunc(to_date(B.local_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(w.local_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) as timediff
from change c
join WORKFLOW_PROCESS w on w.change_id = c.id
join listentry le on le.ENTRYID = c.CATEGORY
join agileuser as orig on orig.id = c.ORIGINATOR
join agileuser as own on own.id = c.owner
join nodetable as n on n.id = w.state
JOIN WORKFLOW_PROCESS B ON B.order_by = (w.order_by + 1) 
where c.CHANGE_NUMBER='NPI001084' 
order by w.ORDER_BY,local_date ASC
```

Comment: Thank you so much both of you. I am completely new to it and trying to figure out. The above query was giving me expected result before adding that subquery. This query prints same rows multiple times and I am not able to use distinct in any column. Any suggestions?

Comment: The same row multiple times was the source of your issue originally. Just have to refine your query to select only one, or maybe use row_number() function to select the first of any group. Or if they are truly duplicate across all these columns then use SELECT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

What a mess! You should really consider using SQL formatter or - if you can't for some reason - try to format code you write manually. This is unreadable.

Anyway: although subqueries look like a *nice way out* of your problems, generally - avoid them. Most of those can be rewritten so that you properly join tables involved.

If you choose to use them within the `SELECT` statement, you have to make sure that each of them returns a single value.

This returns two or more rows:

```
SELECT (TRUNC (
             TO_DATE (b.local_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
           - TO_DATE (w.local_date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')))
          AS timediff
  FROM workflow_process w
       INNER JOIN workflow_process b ON b.order_by = (w.order_by + 1)
 WHERE     w.change_id = b.change_id
       AND w.change_id = 9946301
```

How to fix it? I don't know, I don't have your tables and have no idea what you want. Simple options might be to:

```
select distinct timediff ...
```

or

```
select max(timediff) ...
```

or

```
select ...
where rownum = 1
```

or some other option, but - again, it depends on something we don't know.